# open exe in hidden mode in vc++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exe

I want to run an .exe file in hidden mode using vc++ in VS2010.

I have tried this code

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


                 Process^ p = Process::Start("Ai.exe");

                 IntPtr calculatorWindowHandle = p->MainWindowHandle;
                 void *calculatorWindowHandle1 = calculatorWindowHandle.ToPointer();
               HWND pHandle = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(calculatorWindowHandle1);

                 ShowWindow(pHandle, SW_HIDE);                  
             }
```

But it is opening the EXE but not in hidden mode.

Can anybody please tell me how it can be done.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does "in hidden mode" mean?

Comment: Thanks for reply... I mean for hidden is that .exe will be open but couldn't be seen on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I found the solution.

I just require to use

```
Sleep(60);
```

After

```
Process^ p = Process::Start("Ai.exe");
```

because starting a process takes some milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If `Ai.exe` is your own application, you can make it hidden just by not having any window in it. Make it Windows application (`/SUBSYSTEM:Windows`), but don't create any window.

If `Ai.exe` is not your application, then my question would be - What do you want to achieve? Why you want that application to be hidden?

Comment: Thanks for reply...Ai.exe is not my own application it is another exe which will be process for some task and it's output will be used in my own application.